# Why reading data in Postgres requires lock?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds-aurora

Using AWS Postgres, I am seeing some issues with `LWLock:lock_manager`.

While investigating the issues, I've found [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/apg-waits.lw-lock-manager.html).

I can't understand **why READING data requires any kind of lock**? And why during spike in traffic this locks causes my DB to throttle?

Comment: `lock_manager` doesn't appear anywhere in the PostgreSQL source. Note that Aurora is substantially different from PostgreSQL. You'd better ask Amazon.

Comment: thanks Laurenz! I didn't know it's Aurora "thing".

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, actually LWLock lock_manager existed before pg13. `Waiting to add or examine locks for backends, or waiting to join or exit a locking group (used by parallel query).` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-stats.html

Comment: @Melkij Ah, you are right. If you see that wait event frequently, it means that you have contention because many concurrent sessions want to lock the same rows. The problem is **not** that they are locking each other out. I have seen that problem with tons of inserts into a table with a foreign key, when all inserted rows reference the same row.

Comment: On the question "why does reading data require any kind of lock" see: [why-do-we-need-read-locks-in-read-write-locks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/419474/why-do-we-need-read-locks-in-read-write-locks)